# SQL Server / web services availability options required

Tags: .net, sql-server, web-services

I have an application that is used to manage customer loyalty points for a supermarket. We have a database that supports our internal call centre application which has operated for about 10 years or so, but more recently we have also exposed a web services layer direct to the database to support a public website, where customers can log in and updated their details directly. The web site is maintained by a third party, which makes changes a little more complicated.

Now, the problem is that there are a few nightly batch jobs which can take hours to run and lock the database for long periods of time. I have been tasked with making sure that the web services aren't affected by these batch jobs. The main job is importing customer transactions from stores and calculating loyalty points.

Our environment is sql server 2008/ .Net 4

I am looking for some suggestions on possible solutions and pros/cons

My ideas so far:

**Create a copy of the databases and use SQL Replication to keep the databases in synch. The web services act against the copy of the databases.**

**pros**

- no conflict between what is happening on the source databases

**cons**

- will have to synch back changes that happen via the web services.
- schema changes will cause the replication to break
- Any updates happening on the master db will have to be pushed out, so could still lock the database

**Allow the web services to read data with(Nolock). Updates from the web services could be scheduled asynchronously via sql broker**

**pros**

- Less complicated setup,

**cons**

- No experience setting up sql broker, not sure how robust it is.
- Unexpected events can still lock the database and bring down the website

**Tune the long running processes to make sure they aren't locking the database**

**pros**

- Would be the least risky option. One of the tables involved has hundreds of millions of rows of data and a composite primary key, so I feel putting in an identity as PK should reduce the lock escalation etc.

**cons**
 - It is likely that there is always going to be some level of locking while these particular jobs run

**Splitting the web services to separate the ones that can be affected by the batch jobs. Treat these in a different way.**

- Sounds like the way to go, I just need to identify the best way to treat these affected web services, for reads and writes.